# QGraphicsItem Pixel Perfect Collision Detector

Tags: c++, qt, collision-detection, qgraphicsitem, qpainterpath

I want to implement a pixel perfect collision detector between two or more  `QGraphicsItem`. The `QGraphicsItem` class provides a collision detector using `QPainterPath` objects, so now I want to load an image from file to a `QPainterPath` with only non-transparent pixels (make an accurate shape of non-transparent pixels), in this way I can use `QGraphicsItem`'s own collision detector to implement a pixel perfect collision detector. I wanted to know if there is any way to do this trick??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QGraphicsPixmapItem when using images with alpha channel. Use

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem::shapeMode(QGraphicsPixmapitem::MaskShape)
```

This extracts a mask based on alpha channel for creating shape.